# how to make sure eclipse load the velocity bundled with my jar

Tags: eclipse-plugin, velocity

I have an eclipse plugin, i use velocity 1.7, which is bundled along with the plugin. When i install the plugin in eclipse and run it, i get the below exception from velocity engine.

```
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does n
ot implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException: The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.re
source.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not ini
tialized correctly.
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeResourceManager(RuntimeInstance.java:725)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:263)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:646)
at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.init(VelocityEngine.java:116)
```

Could it be that some other velocity engine is used instead of the one bundled with the plugin...
please suggest some way to make eclipse use the velocity bundled with my plugin only.